# Foundation 5 row width

Tags: row, zurb-foundation

I wonder what's the purpose of having media queries for XLarge and XXLarge devices in Foundation 5 if row width is only 62.5rem, anyone can obviously change that size, but what's the purpose of having that as a default if in huge screens it will look tiny?

Answer (score 0):

I think that those media queries are used for building the visibility classes (`hidden-for-xlarge-only`, `visible-for-xxlarge-up` etc). Maybe someone at some point would use an 100rem row and need those classes but I must agree that this looks like an edge case.

Answer (score 0):

`xlarge` and `xxlarge` media queries are disabled by default on Foundation 5. For enabling them  you have to overwrite the variable `$include-xl-html-grid-classes: true;` in your config settings.

I've overwritten the default config with the following values and it works fine for me:

```
...
$include-xl-html-grid-classes: true;

// Media Query Ranges
$small-range: (0px, 428px);
$medium-range: (429px, 591px);
$large-range: (592px, 784px);
$xlarge-range: (785px, 980px);
$xxlarge-range: (981px, 99999999px);
...
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Now these media queries have been changed in foundation 5 .

// XLarge screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) { } /* min-width 1441px, xlarge screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) and (max-width: 120em) { } /* min-width 1441px and max-width 1920px, use when QAing xlarge screen-only issues */

// XXLarge screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em) { } /* min-width 1921px, xxlarge screens */

Please check official website http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

Thanks ,
Lakin

Comment: Your website looks tiny in large screen because you may have used css like "max-width:62.5rem"